# label and style sheet in struts 2

Tags: user-interface, tags, struts2, struts-html

i have 2 questions:
1)I want to separate "Enter your Name" in `<td>` and textFiled in other `<td>`.
when i do that these 2 td arent appear in the same vertical alignment.
the first one in top and other in bottom i dont know why that happened???
im forced to do like this:

```
<s:textfield label="Enter your Name" value="" required="true" name="userBean.userName"></s:textfield>
```

but this option doesnt allow me to give label style sheet and the text field has another style sheet.
2)i build a cascade style sheet but i think it still not taken 
please if any body give me tutorial or link for tutorial how to use custom cascade style sheet for using it to Struts2.

Comment: First, set **struts.xml** : `<struts>` `<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />` `</struts>`, and don't use attribute `label`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe simple theme

```
<s:textfield theme="simple" value="" required="true" name="userBean.userName"></s:textfield>
```

struts2 by default puts table with class="wwFormTable" around your forms and tags.You can either modify that css class or use simple theme as given above